# CSSProperties TextAlignProperty type error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using React 16.8 with Typescript "@zeit/next-typescript": "1.1.0"

I have inline-style interface. And There is object using `IInputInlineStyle` interface.

```
interface IInputInlineStyle {
    padding: string;
    textAlign?: string;
    paddingLeft?: string | number;
    color?: string;
}

 const inputInlineStyle: IInputInlineStyle = {
            padding,
            textAlign
        };
```

But I got this error message.

> Error:(155, 21) TS2322: Type 'IInputInlineStyle' is not assignable to type 'CSSProperties'.
>
> Types of property 'textAlign' are incompatible.
>
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'TextAlignProperty'.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 19):

Since Typescript 3.4 you can make use of the `as const` notation:

```
const inputInlineStyle = {
  textAlign: 'center' as const
};
```

Source - https://github.com/typestyle/typestyle/issues/281#issuecomment-535359254

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried changing the `textAlign` property to from type `string` to type `TextAlignProperty`?

Comment: I don't know where is defined `TextAlignProperty`